# Converting IP from C string to unsigned int?

Tags: c, windows, linux, ip

I've got a quick question; I have an IPv4 in a C string (say "192.168.0.1") and I want to convert it to an uint32_t. I'm sure there should be some function for that but I havn't found it. Any ideas?

Comment: `uint32_t` is not an appropriate type for addresses. This is 2011 and modern software **must** support IPv6. Store addresses as strings for any data interchange, and in the `struct addrinfo *` returned by `getaddrinfo` for internal user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function is called `inet_aton`.

```
int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *inp);
```

The structure in_addr is defined in `<netinet/in.h>` as:

```
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

struct in_addr {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
};
```

Of course you can also use the newer function `inet_pton`.

Comment: dosn't inet_aton convert the char* into an sockaddr struct?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Yes, and inside it you will find `s_addr` which is `unit32_t`

Comment: When it comes to windows i guess you are stuck with inet_addr? Since inet_aton dosnt seem to be defined in windows

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Windows has `inet_pton`.

Comment: inet_pton is only supported after windows vista. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx As far as I know for xp you have to use inet_aton.

Comment: @rem7 Yes the page says "Minimum supported client.. Vista".

Comment: oops. I guess that's a >=vista ;)