# Comparing strings containing IPv4 addresses in C

Tags: c, ipv4

I have two strings `ip1 = "192.168.145.123"` and `ip2 = "172.167.234.120"`.

I can compare these two strings for equality:

```
strncmp(ip1,ip2) == 0
```

**However *how* can I find out**

```
if (ip1 > ip2) {
    ...
}
```

**What I have tried**

I can use sscanf:

```
sscanf(ip1,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&s1,&s2,&s3,&s4)
```

and store the numbers and compare.
However in 32 bit I can't store the numbers as integers due to the upper limit.

Thus I have no choice but to compare the integers as strings.

Comment: To what "upper limit" are you referring? (and if it is the sign-ness of `int`, any reason you're not using `unsigned int` and `"%u"` for reading them )?

Comment: An IPV4 address can be stored perfectly in a 4byte wide unsigned integer. As also shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18291062/694576 to one of **your** questions.

Comment: Of course you can store the numbers in an integer. An ip-address is 32 bits, and fits just fine in an `unsigned int` on most systems.

Comment: You might also want to check e.g. [`inet_pton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg pretty sure he wants 192.168.1.1 to be *greater* than  10.0.0.1. Storing them in an 32bit `int` won't do that, but an `unsigned int` will.

Comment: What is wrong with the sscanf method you used in your method? You can just compare the numbers returned until you find that the first ip is larger or the opposite

Comment: Why not just compare them lexicographically as strings? There is no meaningful ordering to IP addresses; 172.167.234.120 is not earlier in time than 192.168.145.123, nor farther east or faster. One use for ordering things is to manage them in a data structure. For that purpose, any ordering suffices, so it might as well be whatever you can compute the fastest. String comparison is fine for that, as long as you know there are no leading zeroes. If this is not the purpose, then why do the IP addresses need an ordering?

Comment: what about inet_aton ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: `strcmp("19.12.10.2", "109.122.199.237")` will say that the second address comes before the first, whereas most people would say that the first comes before the second.  If the address uses 3-digit triples throughout, comparison is valid (but leading zeroes are non-standard in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation); if there are any 2-digit or 1-digit numbers, then comparisons can give the wrong answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, of course. I blame lack of coffee :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course there is an order in IP adresses, e.g. by network part in routing tables. And you might want to qsort() a list of IP adresses to use bsearch() to see if one is already in a table. Don't jump to conclusions, Watson :-)

Comment: @Jens: Regarding searching a table: My comment addressed that. All you need to organize and search a table is an ordering. Lexicographic ordering of the string satisfies that. Regarding routing: Routing tables establish some organization but not a total order. And none of the answers here about comparing by number give any regard to routing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the sexy way, store all values in *one* unsigned integer and compare it.

```
  const char* ip1 = "192.168.145.123";
  const char* ip2 = "172.167.234.120";

  unsigned char s1, s2, s3, s4;
  unsigned int uip1, uip2;

  sscanf(ip1,"%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu",&s1,&s2,&s3,&s4);
  uip1 = (s1<<24) | (s2<<16) | (s3<<8) | s4; //store all values in 32bits unsigned int

  sscanf(ip2,"%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu",&s1,&s2,&s3,&s4);
  uip2 = (s1<<24) | (s2<<16) | (s3<<8) | s4;

  if (uip1 > uip2)
  {
    printf("ip1 greater !");   
  }
  else
  {
    printf("ip2 greater or equal !");     
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the calls to `sscanf()` use `%hhu`?

Comment: Please **do not `sscanf()`.** Use `strtoul()` instead.

Comment: @H2CO3: Why not use `sscanf()`?  What concern is addressed by using `strtoul()` compared with `sscanf()`?  Testing the results of `strtoul()` is a surprisingly delicate business, though since the values should be in the range 0..255 for this data, it should be a whole heap simpler to validate than the general 'any value is valid' case.

Comment: @H2CO3 Why? Using sscanf is perfectly ok (but one should test the return value). It's much easier to sscanf four numbers than using strtok or whatever to look for the dots.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and Jens: `sscanf()` may work *in this case,* not in others. It's not that it doesn't work. It works, if used properly. But it's hard to get right the usage of `scanf()` and variants thereof.

Comment: @H2CO3: OK.  One issue is "to what extent is it legitimate to assume that the IPv4 address string being parsed is valid (and just needs interpreting) versus the IPv4 address string could be garbage". If you're allowed to assume 'it is valid; please parse', then not checking the return from `sscanf()` etc is OK (it won't fail if the string is valid).  If it is not guaranteed to be valid, there is more work to be done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, sure. My point is merely that if one isn't able to figure out how to convert a string to an integer, he will most likely get `sscanf()` wrong.

Comment: So that is a reason to educate on the correct use of `sscanf()`; it is not a reason to demand the use of `strtoul()` which has to be handled very carefully (much more carefully than `sscanf()`) to detect all error conditions correctly.  Granted, `strtoul()` will detect errors (like overflow) that `sscanf()` doesn't — but the blanket "do not use" is too sweeping; it needs a more nuanced response.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Perhaps one of you could explain what error conditions / issues could arise in the usage of either sscanf() or strtoul() ??

Comment: @NickHalden: In 600-characters? Kinda tough! Using `strtoul()`, you have to set `errno` to 0 before calling it, and (in general) test for ULONG_MIN and ULONG_MAX return values with ERANGE, and a return value of 0 with the end pointer set to the start (no conversion possible), plus decide what to do if the character after the converted number isn't what you expected, and so on. With `sscanf()`, there's no guarantee that overflow will be detected at all (and it isn't reported); you have to check that you got the correct number of conversions, maybe using `%n` to find where the conversions ended.

Comment: Note that `%u` interprets an 'optionally signed decimal integer', so `sscanf()` — and `strtoul()` — will not report an error given `-123` as one of the dotted-decimal components of the IP address, and won't object to `+123` either. This is where the validation vs conversion issue arises; if you simply need to convert a known-to-be-valid number, you can stop worrying about most of the error conditions. If you have to check whether it is valid, you have to do a lot more work — I would be sorely tempted to apply a regex to the string to check its form, and only then parse it.

Comment: thanks, i had the same  problem and your solution was helpful !

Answer (score 14):

Is it worth mentionning that there is also inet_aton ?

You can find the man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html), below is a short description and a short synopsis.

This solution will work on most POSIX systems, but I'm sure there is some equivalent in the Windows APIs, and even some abstraction wrapper.

> inet_ntoa() is specified in POSIX.1-2001.  inet_aton() is not specified in POSIX.1-2001, but is available on most systems.

---

> ### Linux Programmer's Manual
>
> inet_aton()  converts  the  Internet  host  address  cp  from the IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary form (in network byte order) and stores it in the structure that inp points to.

### SYNOPSIS

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *inp);
char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);
```

---

### EXAMPLE

An example of the use of inet_aton() and inet_ntoa() is shown below.  Here are some example runs:

> ```
>        $ ./a.out 226.000.000.037      # Last byte is in octal
>        226.0.0.31
>        $ ./a.out 0x7f.1               # First byte is in hex
>        127.0.0.1
> ```

Program source

```
   #define _BSD_SOURCE
   #include <arpa/inet.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       struct in_addr addr;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "%s <dotted-address>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (inet_aton(argv[1], &addr) == 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Invalid address\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

---

### Further informations

- Byte ordering (@Jonathan Leffler)

  > The  inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address `in`, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.
  >   `inet_aton()`  converts  the  Internet  host  address  `cp`  from the IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary form (in network byte order) and stores it in the structure that `inp` points to.
- Structure of `in_addr` (@POW)

  > The structure in_addr as used in inet_ntoa(), inet_makeaddr(), inet_lnaof() and inet_netof() is defined in  as:

  ```
     typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

     struct in_addr {
         in_addr_t s_addr;
     };
  ```
- Compare to address independently of computer-endianness
  Addresses in `in_addr` are in network byte order (big-endian), so as pointed by @glglgl, you have to use `ntohl`, whose man page is available [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ntohl.3.html).

  > The `ntohl()` function converts the unsigned integer `netlong` from network byte order to host byte order.

  ```
  uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
  ```

Comment: Does this give the correct ordering on both big-endian and little-endian machines?  The network ordering need not be the native ordering, so I suspect it could get confused.  If it works correctly, then this is a good answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You'll get a "memory dump" with `inet_aton()` which is in the network byte order. A `ntohl()` will give you the correct ordering, then.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not sure does this answer 

_"how can I find out
`if (ip1 > ip2) { ...}`"_ ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, edited my post with an additional quote, which should answer your question.

Comment: @POW, I edit with the structure of the `struct in_addr`, so you can get the numerical value :)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  My concern is that `inet_aton()` converts the string into a network order address, but network order (big-endian) won't compare accurately on Intel (little-endian) machines.  I think @glglgl more or less agrees with me. To get the result comparable on the machine, you have to convert the network order value to host order, using `ntohl()`, for example.  Then you can do the comparison with the native values.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

unsigned int convIP(const char ip[]) {
    unsigned char s1, s2, s3, s4;

    if (sscanf(ip, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4) != 4)
        return 0;

    /* Create a 32 bit Integer using left shift & bitwise OR
            MSB                                            LSB
            +-----8----+-----8------+-----8-----+----8-----+
            |    s1    |     s2     |    s3     |    s4    |   
            +----------+------------+-----------+----------+
     */
    return  (s1 << 24) | (s2 << 16) | (s3 << 8) | (s4 << 0);

}

int ipComp(const char ip1[], const char ip2[]) {
    unsigned int ip_addr1 = convIP(ip1);
    unsigned int ip_addr2 = convIP(ip2);

    return (ip_addr1 >= ip_addr2);

}


int main()
{

    printf("%d\n",ipComp("192.168.145.123","172.167.234.120") ); //1

    printf("%d\n", ipComp("10.0.0.1","192.168.1.1") );  //0

    printf("%d\n",ipComp("192.168.145.123","192.168.145.123")); //1
}
```

**Edit:** As suggested by H2CO3:

You should generally avoid using `sscanf`, instead you can use `strtol()`, like this:

```
unsigned long ip2int(const char *ip)
{
    const char *end = ip + strlen(ip);
    unsigned long n = 0;
    while (ip < end) {
        n <<= 8;
        n |= strtoul(ip, (char **)&ip, 10);
        ip++;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! however i cant seem to understand what is the function of this part `(s1 << 24) | (s2 << 16) | (s3 << 8) | s4`

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `sscanf()` use `%hhu`?

Comment: @alk Agreed, I'm using MINGW and `%hhu` throws a warning with `-Wall`.
Same as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10680635/1870232).
Still I updated

Comment: @DeepakTivari: Regarding `<<`: read about the "left-shift" operator; regarding `|` read about the "bit-wise OR" operator.

Comment: @DeepakTivari - That operation is packing four separate ints into a single unsigned int.  Three of the values have to be shifted to higher order bits, and that's what the shift operator (<<) does.

Comment: @P0W No `sscanf()` please!

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, however your prev implimentation worked like a charm, just wanted to be more clear on the bit wise thingy

Comment: @H2CO3 Updated, sorry, I can't think of anything simpler  for a valid IP address :(

Comment: @P0W No problem. In fact, the `sscanf()` code looks better than your hand-rolled version :P Mind you if I mess around a bit with your code?

Comment: @H2CO3 Awesome !, but just one concern it will convert these `123.123.12.11.1.1, 123.123.12,11.1.1, 123.123.12,11.` as ints too:P
But I guess, it okay, calling function should take care of these.

Comment: @P0W Yes, I haven't made sure to validate the format, indeed.

Comment: @Geoffroy You mean, it should be 0?

Comment: `sscanf(ip, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu"` is _incorrect_ for `s1` is type `int`, not type `unsigned char`.  Recommend instead to use `sscanf(ip, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu"` and type  `unsigned char` for `s1` or  use `sscanf(ip, "%u.%u.%u.%u"` and type  `unsigned` for `s1`.

Comment: Is there any virtue in using `"%3u.%3u.%3u.%3u"` so that if someone tries to slip a 4-digit or more number past the system, the `sscanf()` fails?  Of course, if you're validating the address, you need to ensure that each component is in the range 0..255 afterwards; you can't specify that with `sscanf()` and it will admit 999 even with the `%3u` notation.

Comment: @H2CO3 no, just that you used it in a nice way using `(char **)&ip` :) maybe strtoul second argument should be of type `const char**` as this works, as the characters are not modified, just the pointer's value

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  "%3u.%3u..." does have some value, if for nothing else, constraining, a bit, the length of the scan.  It could be a problem for the last byte as "123.123.123.1234" would likely scan incorrectly with "%3u.%3u..." and sscanf() returning 4.

Comment: @chux You could use `sscanf(ip, "%3u.%3u.%3u.%3u%c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4, &dummy)` and check if the result is 5 (then it is an error) or 4 (then it is ok).

Comment: @Geoffroy No, it's `(char **)` intentionally, it's declared like so in `strtoul()`'s prototype, and omitting the cast causes a warning, [because it's wrong](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

Answer (score 1):

A pedantic "after the accepted answer" answer.  **Error checking** employed.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int IPstringToUns32(const char *IPString, uint32_t *IPNumber) {
  uint8_t c[4];  // LSByte in c[0]
  char ch;
  const char * format = "%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8 "%c";
  if (4 != sscanf(IPString, format, &c[3], &c[2], &c[1], &c[0], &ch)) {
    return 1; // parse error
  }
  *IPNumber = (((uint32_t) c[3]) << 24) | (((uint32_t) c[2]) << 16)
      | (((uint32_t) c[1]) << 8) | ((uint32_t) c[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Suppose one could instead use `uint_fast32_t`.  This solution allows for leading white space before digits.

[Edit] Added classic `%c` at the end of the format.  Thanks to @glglgl.

Comment: Using an array here has no point. Of course, it is ok, but it has no benefits over e. g. `uint8_t c1, c2, c3, c4`.

Comment: glglgl  The scan count != 4 is not shown.  An indexed array allows looped handing of unset values there.  Beginning variable ID from 1 rather than idiomatic 0 is interesting.  I find starting at 0 than 1 more consistent in the C language.  I see the "((uint32_t) c[3]) << 24" as ""((uint32_t) c[3]) << 8*3 as a reduction in magic numbers.  Seems more of a style issue.  Suggest you pose it as SO question should you find it compelling.

Comment: Was just meant to be a suggestion. At the end, it is a matter of personal style, I think.

Comment: @glglgl  Concur about style.  BTW: I've been bit too often when asserting the certainty of non-existence "Using ... has no point". ;-)